# Laravel- (layout.blade.php inside layout folder) how do i link external css,js in index.blade.php

Tags: laravel-5

```
@extends('layout/layout.blade.php')
```

Having `layout.blade.php` it contains `css`,`js`. and have to link with `index.blade.php`. i tried `@extends('layout.layout')`, is not working.

Comment: Maybe your folder name is wrong. You can try rename layout folder to something different and check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use;

```
src="{{ asset('path/css or js') }}"
```